# How to set "max_result_window" in Elasticsearch 7 NEST 7

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

In default elastic search only returns 10k results. But I need to go to the last page which exceeds 10k results.

I did some reach and found a solution by setting **"max_result_window" : 100000**
And I execute it in Kibana and  even more thanx 5000pages works fine after this setting.

```
PUT jm-stage-products/_settings
{ 
  "max_result_window" : 100000 
}
```

Now I need to include this setting when I'm creating an index in my source code.But I coundn't find a way to do it.
This is my index create function. How should I set "max_result_window" : 100000?

```
  public string InitIndexing()
        {
            var indexName = string.Format(_config.ElasticIndexName, _config.HostingEnvironment);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if (!_client.Indices.Exists(indexName).Exists)
            {
                //----------------------------------------------
                var indexSettings = new IndexSettings
                {
                    NumberOfReplicas = 0, // If this is set to 1 or more, then the index becomes yellow.
                    NumberOfShards = 5,                  
                };
             
                var indexConfig = new IndexState
                {
                    Settings = indexSettings
                };
                var createIndexResponses = _client.Indices.Create(indexName, c => c
                                          .InitializeUsing(indexConfig)                      
                                         .Map<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(m => m.AutoMap())
               );
                return createIndexResponses.DebugInformation;
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{_config.ElasticIndexName} already exists";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an index with `max_result_window` setting with following code snippet:

```
var createIndexResponse = await elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync("index_name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Setting(UpdatableIndexSettings.MaxResultWindow, 100000)))
```

Already existing index can be updated with this fluent syntax:

```
await elasticClient.Indices.UpdateSettingsAsync("index_name", s => s
    .IndexSettings(i => i.Setting(UpdatableIndexSettings.MaxResultWindow, 100000)));
```

Comment: In NEST version 6, there is no property named "MaxResultWindow" in "UpdatableIndexSettings" class. To set the result window in NEST 6, use the following code,
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
await client.CreateIndexAsync(indexname, i => i
                .Settings(s => s
                .Setting("index.max_result_window", 10000)));

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `nest` but it can be easily done while creating the index and
below is the REST API to show that.

PUT HTTP://localhost:9200/your-index-name/

```
{
    "settings": {
        "max_result_window" : 1000000 // note this
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "first_name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "last_name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check if its created successfully in index-settings

GET HTTP://localhost:9200/your-index-name/_settings

```
{
    "so_1": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "so_1",
                "max_result_window": "1000000", // note this
                "creation_date": "1601273239277",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "eHBxaGf2TBG9GdmG5bvwkQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7080099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.. This is working. I already tried that. But I need to implement it using NEST 7.

Answer (score 1):

In kibana it looks like this

```
PUT index_name/_settings
{
  "max_result_window": 10000
}
```